# jQuery draw line between divs on onload

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

[Demo draw line](http://kennykee.com/demo/draw-line/)

Basically I'm doing exactly this with multiple elements. Using the same code.

I want the lines elements to `draw` when the page loads. Currently I need to move a div (twice?) for the script to run.

Very new to JavaScript. Have searched as far as I'm capable with the terms I'm familiar with! 
Any pointers appreciated.

edit:

If I modify drag to this:
        create: function(event, ui){
The lines show when loaded. However when the divs are moved, the line does not follow.

Thanks!

```
var boxCenterXOffset = 50;
var boxCenterYOffset = 50;
var boxCenterZOffset = 50;



$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".box").draggable({ delay: 0, distance: 0 },{
        drag: function(event, ui){

var x1 = $("#box1").offset().left + boxCenterXOffset;
var x2 = $("#box2").offset().left + boxCenterXOffset;
var x3 = $("#box3").offset().left + boxCenterXOffset;

var y1 = $("#box1").offset().top + boxCenterYOffset;
var y2 = $("#box2").offset().top + boxCenterYOffset;
var y3 = $("#box3").offset().top + boxCenterYOffset;


var hypotenuse  = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
var hypotenuse2 = Math.sqrt((x2-x3)*(x2-x3) + (y2-y3)*(y2-y3));

var angle  = Math.atan2((y1-y2), (x1-x2)) *  (180/Math.PI);
var angle2 = Math.atan2((y2-y3), (x2-x3)) *  (180/Math.PI);

if(angle >= 90 && angle < 180){
        y1 = y1 - (y1-y2);
        }
        if(angle > 0 && angle < 90){
        x1 = x1 - (x1-x2);
        y1 = y1 - (y1-y2);
        }
        if(angle <= 0 && angle > -90){
        x1 = x1 - (x1-x2);
        }

if(angle2 >= 90 && angle2 < 180){
        y2 = y2 - (y2-y3);
        }
        if(angle2 > 0 && angle2 < 90){
        x2 = x2 - (x2-x3);
        y2 = y2 - (y2-y3);
        }
        if(angle2 <= 0 && angle2 > -90){
        x2 = x2 - (x2-x3);
        }

$("#line").queue(function(){
$(this).offset({top: y1, left: x1});
$(this).dequeue();
}).queue(function(){
$(this).width(hypotenuse);
$(this).dequeue();
}).queue(function(){
$(this).rotate(angle);
$(this).dequeue();
});

$("#line2").queue(function(){
$(this).offset({top: y2, left: x2});
$(this).dequeue();
}).queue(function(){
$(this).width(hypotenuse2);
$(this).dequeue();
}).queue(function(){
$(this).rotate(angle2);
$(this).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: Please include the code here instead of linking to it. That way your question is still useful to others when the linked page changes. It also helps others with similar problems to find your question with a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS way:

Call your function for drawing / updating the line(s) with an event listener for the document load event. It'd look something like this

```
document.addEventListener("load", function_to_draw_line);
```

Your code will be executed when the DOM has loaded.

The JQuery way:

You already have a function to be called when either of the divs are dragged. Define this function with a name, and attach it to both the drag event, and the create event. The function should look like this:

```
function drawLine(event,ui) {
    //put your function in here
}
```

Then, your $(document).ready should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").draggable({ delay: 0, distance: 0 },{
        drag: drawLine,
        create: drawLine
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Ted

Added the script to the question. Could you please me where specifically to add event?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jeff if this answer was a solution, would you mind accepting it?